# Tax tab in magento is not visible under sales menu

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

In my Magento admin panel under sales Menu tax tab is not visible.
Can some tell me how to enable it.
And I am login as a Admin user and as a Admin user i have all the permission.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you disabled module output for this module in "System > Configuration > Advanced" and this module rewrites blocks from Mage_Tax, without overriding getModuleName() (an often overlooked detail). Now these blocks belong to the module and will be hidden according to the configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I don't know how ....
but this module is disable in Admin panel I enabled and tax tab is show now.